# JSON parsing error in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, parsing

I am trying to parse this JSON in Objective-C. The response object looks thus:

```
(
  {
    "Year": "2003",
    "SumOfYear": "0.20"
  },
  {
    "Year": "2004",
    "SumOfYear": "0.64"
  },
  {
    "Year": "2005",
    "SumOfYear": "0.90"
  }
)
```

I tried the following

```
NSDictionary* dictionaryObtained = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"dict = %@",dictionaryObtained);
NSDictionary *yearsObtained = [dictionaryObtained objectForKey:@"Year"];
```

But I obtain the following error:

```
-[__NSCFArray bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18a3bfd0
```

Where am I going wrong?
 I want to obtain all the `Year` in a `NSArray` and all the `SumOfYear` in another `NSArray`.

The error is from this line

```
NSDictionary* dictionaryObtained = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: Why do you use escape character for year ?
(on the last line).

Comment: what is ur dictionary looks like when u print it ?

Comment: @Roma-MT - Please see my edit above

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is, doesnt it? You got an array of dictionaries here.

Comment: xcode does not parse JSON. it is just an IDE.

Comment: @vikingosegundo what is wrong ? "I am trying to parse this JSON in xcode" He tries to parse JSON in IDE called xcode he could try it on visual studio or eclipse but he trying in xcode ...
The question tagged as Objective-C not xcode

Comment: If you actually look at the JSON, you have an array containing "objects" (dictionaries).  Go to json.org and spend the 5-10 minutes it takes to learn the JSON syntax -- it's a very wise investment of your time.

Comment: What line is the above error coming from???  It appears that your "response object" is already parsed and does not need to be fed into NSJSONSerialization again.

Comment: from the comments: `[manager POST:postRequestString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)` The goal of libraries like AFNetworking is to transform incoming data to something useful. My I suggest to RTFM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong(right format - but not to match your code) the json. 
If you want your code to work this is the correct:

```
{ "Year":
    [
          {
          "Year": "2003",
          "SumOfYear": "0.20"
          },
          {
          "Year": "2004",
          "SumOfYear": "0.64"
          },
          {
          "Year": "2005",
          "SumOfYear": "0.90"
          }
     ]
}
```

Your json as it is can be parsed:

```
for(NSDictionary *myDict in jsonObj){
     NSString *year = [myDict objectForKey:@"Year"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears (hard to tell for sure without better info from you) that `responseObject` has already been parsed from JSON string into Objective-C objects.  Therefore you *should not* run it through NSJSONSerialization again.

But what you have is an NSArray, so, assuming you want to collect an array of the "Year" values, you need something along the lines of:

```
NSMutableArray* yearsObtained = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary* dictionaryObtained in responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"dict = %@",dictionaryObtained);
    NSString* year = [dictionaryObtained objectForKey:@"Year"];
    NSLog(@"year = %@", year);
    [yearsObtained addObject:year];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do it like that:

```
NSArray * dataArray =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];
for(NSDictionary * diction in dataArray)
{ 
    NSLog(@"%@",[diction objectForKey:@"Year"]);
}
```

because you have an array of dictionaries you should put a JSONSerialization inside an NSArray
then to go inside it with dictionary thus u can get to your years as you wish.

From comments below it seems like your `responseObject` is already parsed
so you can just go

```
 for(NSDictionary* dict in responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Year"]);
 }
```

Comment: what `responseObject` is ? is it NSData ?

Comment: this is what I use `    [manager POST:postRequestString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)`

Comment: Where the error triggers exactly on what line ?(try to debug it)

Comment: His problem is that "responseObject" has already been parsed and is an NSArray.

Comment: @HotLicks Updated the answer with that helpful note , hope it will work now )

Comment: well I see it doesnt matter anymore ))

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to parse your JSON and get two arrays is

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *years = [jsonArray valueForKeyPath:@"Year"];
NSArray *sums = [jsonArray valueForKeyPath:@"SumOfYear"];
```

KVC is a great instrument for parsing data structures.

Comment: I tried this but get the same error. Do you mean `responseObject` for `jsonArray`?

Comment: I've just tried it with your array. It is OK! By the way, it is absolutely the same as for (NSDictionary *myDict in jsonArray) if your jsonArray is OK.

Comment: No, I mean the Array which we get from [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: ...]